# How can I expose React Hook outside of my React Functional Component

Tags: reactjs

I have a React Functional Component like this:

```
export const MyParentComponent = (props: Props) => {
    const [myObjects, setMyObjects = React.useState< MyClass[] | undefined>(undefined);

  //...
}
```

I have an array of 'MyClass' objects, in `myObjects` and put that in the 'State' of React since that will affect `MyParentComponent` rendering.

My question is how can I expose `setMyObjects` method to class outside of MyParentComponent so that the caller can set a new array of `MyObjects` and trigger a rendering of MyParentComponent ?

Comment: Pass `setMyObjects` funcion as a prop for desired component and use that function inside that component. For this you have to put this component as a descendant of `MyParentComponent`.

Comment: Do you want to update the MyClass array in a child component of MyParentComponent or the parent?

Comment: Thanks. Why this compontent needs to be a descendant  of `MyParentComponent` ? Can I pass `setMyObjects ` function to any Typescript classs in my Web application wihch is not a Component?

Comment: @n179911a if it's not a descendant, move the state the the closest common ancestor. See react docs: [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the parent component to be able to change the state, you'd either

- Make `myObjects` a state of the parent component or
- Initialize the `myObjects` state with the props passed from the parent component

Unless having the state inside the component prevents you from making your component a [pure component](https://blog.logrocket.com/what-are-react-pure-functional-components/#what-is-pure-component-react), I'd typically recommend the latter:

```js
const {
  useState
} = React;

const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const [myObjects, setMyObjects] = useState(props.myObjects)

  return ( 
    <div>Rendering from MyComponent
      <ul>
        {myObjects.map(o => <li>{o}</li>)}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

const MyParentComponent = () => {
  const objects = ['object1 from MyParentComponent', 'object2  from MyParentComponent', 'object3  from MyParentComponent'];
  return (<MyComponent myObjects={objects} />);
}

ReactDOM.render( <MyParentComponent / > ,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

since you want to change the state of `MyParentComponent` in outside of that component, that outside component need to be a child, since you can need to pass the `setMyObjects` function as a prop.  In other way you can you react feature called `Context API` to access the state of a component which is not Descendant.
[React Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

This is a simple scenario that elaborates how to change the state of the parent component inside the child component by passing setState function as a prop to child.

```
const Movie = () => { // This is the Parent component which render movies.
const movies = [
{ id: 1, title: "Batman", ratings: 8 },
{ id: 2, title: "Avengers", ratings: 8 },
{ id: 1, title: "Dune", ratings: 9 }
];
const [myObjects, setMyObjects] = useState(movies);
return (
<div>
  {myObjects.map((movie) => (
    <p>{movie.title}</p>
  ))}
  <ChangeMovie changeMovieList={setMyObjects}/> // This is the child component which handle changing the state of Movie(Parent). Here pass the state change function as a prop(changeMovieList) to child. Then we can use that to change the state inside that component.
</div>
);
};

export default Movie;


const ChangeMovie = (props) => { // This is the child component.
const changeList = () => {
props.changeMovieList([ // here we change the state of Movie(Parent Component) inside child using the function passed.
  { id: 1, title: "Superman", ratings: 8 },
  { id: 2, title: "Titanic", ratings: 8 },
  { id: 1, title: "Fast & Furious 8", ratings: 9 }
]);
};

return (
<>
  <button onClick={changeList}>Change Movie List</button>
</>
);
};

export default ChangeMovie;
```

Check this [demo sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/update-parent-inside-child-72037418-muvp7k?file=/src/Movie.js) I created to elaborate this.